# Compiling error in rust: failed to run custom build command

Tags: rust, terminal, compilation

I don't quite know what I am looking at, I'm quite certain that this is not my fault

```
PS C:\Users\alexa\Documents\UNIVERSITEIT\2_MASTER\DECISION MAKING FOR BUSINESS\CASE_E\shift_scheduling_code> cargo run
   Compiling num-traits v0.2.15
   Compiling num-integer v0.1.45
error: failed to run custom build command for `num-traits v0.2.15`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `C:\Users\alexa\Documents\UNIVERSITEIT\2_MASTER\DECISION MAKING FOR BUSINESS\CASE_E\shift_scheduling_code\target\debug\build\num-traits-0ab924901b158460\build-script-build` (exit code: 101)
  --- stderr
  thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Error { kind: Other("output path is not a writable directory") }', C:\Users\alexa\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\autocfg-1.1.0\src\lib.rs:128:20
  note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
error: failed to run custom build command for `num-integer v0.1.45`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `C:\Users\alexa\Documents\UNIVERSITEIT\2_MASTER\DECISION MAKING FOR BUSINESS\CASE_E\shift_scheduling_code\target\debug\build\num-integer-7dbeca75e83a8205\build-script-build` (exit code: 101)
  --- stderr
  thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Error { kind: Other("output path is not a writable directory") }', C:\Users\alexa\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\autocfg-1.1.0\src\lib.rs:128:20
  note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
PS C:\Users\alexa\Documents\UNIVERSITEIT\2_MASTER\DECISION MAKING FOR BUSINESS\CASE_E\shift_scheduling_code>
```

I don't really know where to begin solving this problem

Comment: Have you tried `cargo clean` then retrying?

Comment: That's also a very long path. You may be running into [Windows path length limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation).

Comment: when i run this command as an admin this shows up

Comment: error: could not remove build directory

Caused by:
  failed to remove directory `C:\Users\alexa\Documents\UNIVERSITEIT\2_MASTER\DECISION MAKING FOR BUSINESS\CASE_E\shift_scheduling_code\target\debug\.fingerprint\autocfg-38ce632ae4947f24`

Caused by:
  Access is denied. (os error 5)

Comment: Try manually deleting the `target` directory. You have a directory permissions mismatch.